# C# Image rotation using timer

Tags: c#

I am beginner C# user using WFA.Below is my code to get images to rotate every 4 ticks. please could I have some assistance to what I might have done incorrect.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int time = 0;
    int pic = 0;     

    {
        if (time >= 4)
        pic++;
        this.picBox1.Image = ImageList.Images[pic];
        pic++;
        if (time == 4 || time == 8 || time == 12 || time == 16)
        this.lblCompany.Visible = true;
        this.lsbHistory.ValueMember = ("User Clicks on at ___+ DateTime.Now.ToshortDateString");
```

Comment: your problem description does not allow for a good understanding, the code is not commented and people are forced to guess what is actually happening in your program. Such a post is prone to be voted to close it. Please try to add more information

Answer (score 0):

every time your tick event gets called you set time to 0, that means it is lower then 4. you should take both time and pic values out of the event and reset time to 0 after.

I'd reccomend reading this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

on how to use breakpoints to have a beter look at what's happening in your code

```
private int time = 0;
private int pic = 0; 

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     time++;
     if (time >= 4)
     {
          pic++;
          time = 0;
          this.picBox1.Image = ImageList.Images[pic];
          //other logic you might have
```